# Как применить parameter pack (pack expansion) на enable_if (until C++20 SFINAE)?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, sfinae

Основная проблема в том, что `paremeter pack` должен быть последним параметром в списке, а до него о `Ts` ещё ничего не известно. Но и при выносе `enable_if` за пределы параметров шаблона ничего не меняется. Вот:

```
template<typename T>
using RemoveCVR = std::remove_reference_t<std::remove_cv_t<T>>;
    
template<typename T1, typename T2>
static inline constexpr bool IsSimilar =
    std::is_same_v<RemoveCVR<T1>,RemoveCVR<T2>>;
    
template<
    typename... Ts,
    typename std::enable_if_t<IsSimilar<Ts,std::string>>...
>
void f();

template<
    typename std::enable_if_t<IsSimilar<Ts,std::string>>...,
    typename... Ts
>
void f();

template<typename... Ts>
typename std::enable_if_t<IsSimilar<Ts,std::string>>... f();
```

Есть ли способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выносить за параметры шаблона следует правильно:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
using RemoveCVR = std::remove_reference_t<std::remove_cv_t<T>>;
    
template<typename T1, typename T2>
static inline constexpr bool IsSimilar =
    std::is_same_v<RemoveCVR<T1>,RemoveCVR<T2>>;
    
template<typename... Ts>
std::enable_if_t<(IsSimilar<Ts,std::string> and...)> f()
{
    ::std::cout << "test\n";
}

template<typename... Ts>
std::enable_if_t<not (IsSimilar<Ts,std::string> and...)> f()
{
    ::std::cout << "test2\n";
}

int main()
{
    f<std::string>();
    f<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

> test
> test2

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:52,endLineNumber:19,positionColumn:52,positionLineNumber:19,selectionStartColumn:52,selectionStartLineNumber:19,startColumn:52,startLineNumber:19),source:%27%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Ausing+RemoveCVR+%3D+std::remove_reference_t%3Cstd::remove_cv_t%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0A++++%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T1,+typename+T2%3E%0Astatic+inline+constexpr+bool+IsSimilar+%3D%0A++++std::is_same_v%3CRemoveCVR%3CT1%3E,RemoveCVR%3CT2%3E%3E%3B%0A++++%0Atemplate%3Ctypename...+Ts%3E%0Astd::enable_if_t%3C(IsSimilar%3CTs,std::string%3E+and+...)%3E+f()%0A%7B%0A++++::std::cout+%3C%3C+%22test%5Cn%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename...+Ts%3E%0Astd::enable_if_t%3Cnot+(IsSimilar%3CTs,std::string%3E+and+...)%3E+f()%0A%7B%0A++++::std::cout+%3C%3C+%22test2%5Cn%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++f%3Cstd::string%3E()%3B%0A++++f%3Cint%3E()%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g122,compilerName:%27%27,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wpedantic%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

A еще можно использовать `if constexpr (IsSimilar<Ts,std::string> and ...)`.

Comment: Норм, что-то сразу в голову не пришло. Это уже `fold expression` целый.

Comment: Забавно, но я только сейчас понял смысл выноса `std::enable_if` за скобки шаблонных параметров. Он должен вернуть тип возвращаемого значения. Вроде элементарно, но я на это смотрел как на магию =)